# How to properly start a process that will daemonize using Go?

Tags: linux, go

I write Go program that will run another Go program that will daemonize.

I am wondering how much time the first program must wait before its child process is daemonising.

```
cmd := exec.Command(path1)
cmd.Start()
    // exit here
```

or

```
cmd := exec.Command(path1)
cmd.Run()
    // exit here
```

or

```
cmd := exec.Command(path1)
cmd.Start()
time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    // exit here
```

If I use `cmd.Run()` what command/action in started daemon program will end "waiting" in first program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Daemonizing a process is [just a fancy way of forking the process](http://www.ics.uzh.ch/~dpotter/howto/daemonize). That means that the process you start will exit as soon as the daemonized process is started. Therefore you want to use `Run`, which will wait for the started process to return (the successful fork).

```
Process A:
|
|`-- run(B)
|    Process B:
|    |
|    |`-- daemonize(C)
|    |
|     `-- exit
|
 `-- daemonizing done
```

If you want to wait for a state of the daemon, the most reliable way is to be signalled by the daemon. For example using a socket, a file or shared memory.

Comment: Does `exec` in my case replace `fork` in common daemonizing examples? or started program B must still `fork` and `setsid` or only `setsid` is enough. As I understand `exec.Command(x).Run()` is `fork exec` and second `fork` is not required.

Comment: The call to `setsid` is obligatory to entangle the new process from it's previous [process group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548823/use-and-meaning-of-session-and-process-group-in-unix). However, if you're having trouble understanding daemonization or forking, I would recommend asking a new question instead of discussing it here.