# Timing out a forked process

Tags: perl, fork

I am running a Monte carlo on Multiple processors, but it hangs up a lot. So I put together this perl code to kill the iteration that hangs up the monte carlo and go to the next iteration. But I get some errors, I have not figure out yet.
I think it sleeps too long and it will delete the out.mt0 file before it will look for it.
This is the code:

```
my $pid = fork();
die "Could not fork\n" if not defined $pid;

if ($pid == 0) {
    print "In child\n";   
    system("hspice -i mont_read.sp -o out -mt 4"); wait;
    sleep(.8); wait;
    exit(0);
}

print "In parent \n";

$i = 0;    
$mont_number = $j - 1;

out: while (1) {
    $res = waitpid($pid, WNOHANG);    
    if ($res == -1) {
        print "Successful Exit Process Detected\n";
        system("mv out.mt0 mont_read.mt0"); wait;
        sleep(1); wait;
        system("perl monte_stat.pl > rel_out.txt"); wait ;
        system("cat stat_result.txt rel_out.txt > stat_result.tmp"); wait; 
        system("mv stat_result.tmp stat_result.txt"); wait;
        print "\nSim #$mont_number complete\n"; wait;
        last out;    
    }

    if ($res != -1) {    
        if ($i >= $timeout) {
            $hang_count = $hang_count+1;
            system("killall hspice"); wait;
            sleep(1);
            print("time_out complete\n"); wait;
            print "\nSim #$mont_number complete\n"; wait;
            last out; 
        }

        if ($i < $timeout) {
            sleep $slept; wait;
        }
        $i = $i+1;
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
Illegal division by zero at monte_stat.pl line 73,  line 2.
mv: cannot stat `out.mt0': No such file or directory
Illegal division by zero at monte_stat.pl line 73,  line 1.
mv: cannot stat `out.mt0': No such file or directory
Illegal division by zero at monte_stat.pl line 73,  line 1.
mv: cannot stat `out.mt0': No such file or directory
Illegal division by zero at monte_stat.pl line 73.
mv: cannot stat `out.mt0': No such file or directory
Illegal division by zero at monte_stat.pl line 73.
mv: cannot stat `out.mt0': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `out.mt0': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `out.mt0': No such file or directory
Illegal division by zero at monte_stat.pl line 73,  line 3.
mv: cannot stat `out.mt0': No such file or directory
Illegal division by zero at monte_stat.pl line 73,  line 1.
mv: cannot stat `out.mt0': No such file or directory
```

Could anyone give me an idea where to look to debug it.
thanks

Comment: Post a minimal, complete, verifiable example. Don't just link to your code.

Comment: I don't see any threads in the code you've posted.

Comment: @duskwuff I added the thread part. This is the complete code: https://github.com/aliyah3/Multi-thread-with-Perl/blob/master/Times_hspice.perl

Comment: You are forking, not threading. There is a huge difference.

Comment: @simbabque Thanks. I revised the question.

Comment: Which is line 73 ("_at monte_stat.pl line 73_") ?  It looks like your `hsplice` is crashing?  All errors seem to be related to that.

Answer (score 3):

According to the errors it appears that your `hslice` is crashing.  But there are other issues.

Here is first a working example as close as possible to your code.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use POSIX qw(:sys_wait_h);
$| = 1;

my ($timeout, $duration, $sleep_time) = (5, 10, 1);

my $pid = fork // die "Can't fork: $!";

if ($pid == 0)  
{
    exec "echo JOB STARTS; sleep $duration; echo JOB DONE";
    die "exec shouldn't return: $!";
}    
say "Started $pid";
sleep 1;

my $tot_sec;    
while (1) 
{
    my $ret = waitpid $pid, WNOHANG;

    if    ($ret > 0) { say "Child $ret exited with: $?";  last; }
    elsif ($ret < 0) { say "\nNo such process ($ret)";    last; }
    else             { print " . " }

    sleep $sleep_time;

    if (($tot_sec += $sleep_time) > $timeout) {
        say "\nTimeout. Send 15 (SIGTERM) signal to the process.";
        kill 15, $pid;
        last;
    }   
}
```

With `$duration` (of the job) set to `3`, shorter than `$timeout`, we get

```
Started 16848
JOB STARTS
 .  .  . JOB DONE
Child (JOB) 16848 exited with: 0
```

while with `$duration` set to `10` we get

```
Started 16550
JOB STARTS
 .  .  .  .  .
Timeout. Send 15 (SIGTERM) signal to the process.
```

and the job is killed (wait for 5 more seconds – the `JOB DONE` shouldn't show up).

Comments on the code in the question

- If you `fork` only to run a job there is no reason for `system`. Just [exec](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) that program
- No need for [wait](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wait.html) after `system`, and it's wrong.  The `system` includes a wait
- The `wait` doesn't belong after `print` and `sleep`, and it's wrong
- No need to shell out for `killall` in order to kill a process
- If you end up using `system` the program will run in a new process with another PID. Then more is needed to find that PID and kill it. See [Proc::ProcessTable](http://search.cpan.org/~jwb/Proc-ProcessTable-0.53/ProcessTable.pm) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43796534/4653379), for example
- The code above needs checks of whether the process was indeed killed

Substitute your command line instead of `echo ...` and add checks for it as needed.

Another option is to simply sleep for a `$timeout` period and then check whether the job is done (child exited). However, with your approach you can do other things while polling.

Another option is to use [alarm](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html).